# getting error in zend framework in skelton application

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working with Zend Framework 2. I downloaded skelton application. and configured apache.
but I am getting following ERRor ::

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject::offsetGet() must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess::offsetGet()
```

Comment: What's your PHP version? What is the ZF2 version?

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 and zend framework 2

Comment: Yeah, but what version of ZF2?

Comment: I have downloaded it from https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Comment: Actually I am new to zend. So I just started with Skelton application.

Comment: what is the ZF2 version written in your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files?

Comment: "zendframework/zendframework": "2.0.*"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24563/discussion-between-asmita-and-ocramius)

Comment: that looks like incompatible versions to me somehow.. there's no Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject class in the newest versions of ZF2.

Comment: check this - https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/issues/161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject at the moment is using features from php 5.3.5, to fix it for php 5.3.3 do this

put the following lines

```
$libDir = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
require $libDir . '/Zend/Stdlib/compatibility/autoload.php';
require $libDir . '/Zend/Session/compatibility/autoload.php';
```

after the include 'init_autoloader.php'; line in the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version and Zend Framework version are incompatible.
I've learned that PHP 5.3.3 only works with Zend Frameworks up to version 2.2.

The fix mentioned by Zdenek doesn't help to get newer Zend Frameworks (2.3 or 2.4) working with PHP 5.3.3